# Animate layout change of bottom sheet

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

In my application I use a bottom sheet (from the support library) which works great. Now I would like to animate a layout change while the sheet is dragged up. For this I have created a subclass of `BottomSheetCallback` (this is normaly an inner class of a Fragment so not all objects used in this calss are initialized here):

```
public class MyBehavior extends BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback {

    Transition transition;
    float lastOffset = 0;
    Scene scene;

    public PlayerBehavior() {
        TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(getContext());
        transition = inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.player);
        //transition.setDuration(300);

        scene = fullLayout;

        transition.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {
            @Override
            public float getInterpolation(float v) {
                return lastOffset;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if(newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
            TransitionManager.go(scene, transition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, final float slideOffset) {
        scene = (slideOffset > lastOffset) ? smallLayout : fullLayout;
        lastOffset = slideOffset;
    }
}
```

As you can see I also created two `Scene` from different layout files and a custom `Transition` to animate between the scenes with the `TransitionManager`. My problem is that the `Transition` should be based on the `slideOffset` parameter (in range of 0-1) but the `TransitionManager` uses the `Animation` class in the background which is normally time based in Android.

I tried to create the custom Intapolator but this does not work properly. So how can I create a `Transition` which is based on an external variable and not on time?

Comment: Can you provide a visual example. Screenshots for instance?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. BottomSheet offset has value from -1 to 1 and it doesn't always bounce between 0 and 1 or -1 and 0. In some cases it will start at 0.3 and go up to 1.0f. I had same problem in the past. I had to listen for state change events animate based on time.

Comment: Which type of animate you need.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description, I think you are trying to achieve something like google maps bottom sheet behaviour. The layout changes as the **bottomsheet** is dragged up.

If that is what you are trying to achieve then you don't need to enforce custom animations, as the *bottomsheetdialog* itself has those animation behaviour when incorporated inside a parent **Coordinator Layout**.

Here is a sample code of how I'm implementing the same behaviour. It also makes the *FloatingActionButton* invisible when the bottomsheet is dragged up to full screen size :

1. Create a bottomsheetdialog that you want to use inside your main layout

   ```
   public class CustomBottomDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

   String mSomeName;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // if some arguments are passed from the calling activity 
       mSomeName = getArguments().getString("some_name");


   }

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View bottomSheet = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet_layout, container, false);
        // initialise your bottomsheet_layout items here 
       TextView tvName = bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
       tvName.setText(mSomeName); 
       tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
              // do something here
               ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doSomething();
           }
       });

       return bottomSheet;
   }
   }
   ```
2. bottomsheet_layout:

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/nav"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/navigation_tilt_grey"
   app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
   app:elevation="3dp"
   app:fabSize="normal"
   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   app:layout_anchor="@+id/live_dash"
   app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right" />

   <!--BottomSheet-->

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
   android:id="@+id/live_dash"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#F3F3F3"
   android:clipToPadding="true"
   app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBe 
   havior"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="150dp">

   <!--Include your items here, the height of all items combined
   will take the main screen layout size with animation-->

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```
3. Calling this BottomSheet from your activity:

   ```
   public void notifyBottomSheet(String somename){

   BottomSheetDialogFragment customDialogFragment = new CustomBottomDialog();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString("some_name", somename);
   customDialogFragment.setArguments(args);
   customDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), customDialogFragment.getTag());
   customDialogFragment.setCancelable(false); // if you don't wish to hide
   }
   ```

   Hope this solves what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I really feel like I've been staring at this for ages trying to understand how this actually works. How does it know what to animate from and to, if the idea as the question asks is to change the layout as it's dragged, from peek to non-peek?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is what you want but maybe instead of using transition, you can use the function `animate()` since with this function, you can change all things about your animation (time, visibility etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
## Translation Animation ##
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    >
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="-30%p"
        android:duration="900" />
</set>
```

## Main Activity ##

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Animation am= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadeout);
    tv5.startAnimation(am);
    Animation myanim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.translate);
    tv1.startAnimation(myanim);
    myanim.setStartOffset(500);
    Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.translate);
    animation.setStartOffset(1000);
    tv2.startAnimation(animation);
    Animation an= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.translate);
    an.setStartOffset(1500);
    tv3.startAnimation(an);
    Animation ab= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.translate);
    ab.setStartOffset(2000);
    tv4.startAnimation(ab);
    Animation ac= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadein);
    ac.setStartOffset(2500);
    btn1.startAnimation(ac);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To easily slide something off the bottom of the screen, you can use code such as:

```
final int activityHeight = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getHeight();
cardContainer.animate().yBy(activityHeight - cardContainer.getY()).setDuration(SLIDE_OUT_DURATION);
```

where `cardContainer` is the view you are trying to slide off the screen.

See this [blog post](http://zenandroid.io/android-gesture-detection-and-animations-creating-a-swipe-button-control/) for the complete example. Note that you can also use `translationY` instead of `yBy`. Another, more generic way of doing it is with this code:

```
public static ViewPropertyAnimator slideOutToBottom(Context ctx, View view) {
    final int screenHeight = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int[] coords = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
    return view.animate().translationY(screenHeight - coords[Y_INDEX]).setDuration(SLIDE_OUT_DURATION);
}

public static ViewPropertyAnimator slideInFromBottom(Context ctx, View view) {
    final int screenHeight = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int[] coords = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
    view.setTranslationY(screenHeight - coords[Y_INDEX]);
    return view.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(SLIDE_IN_DURATION).setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(1f));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my try using `setWindowsAnimation(res int style)`:

```
mainBottomSheet.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.YourAnimation);
```

and in `styles.xml` add your favorite animations as follow:

```
<style name="YourAnimation" parent="Animation.AppCompat.Dialog">
      <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in</item>
      <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out</item>
</style>
```

Add the following files in `res/anime` directory:

```
<!-- slide_in.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:duration="700"
     android:interpolator="@anim/interpolator_slight_overshoot">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"/>

</set>
```

[bottom-sheet-behavior](/questions/tagged/bottom-sheet-behavior) [android-animation](/questions/tagged/android-animation) [bottom-sheet](/questions/tagged/bottom-sheet)